# Where can I get the TeXLive 2018 torrent file?

Tags: texlive-2018

I have searched the Web but am unable to get a link to the torrent file for TeXLive 2018. Can someone please point me to it if it exists?

Thanks.

Comment: Does [this](https://www.tug.org/texlive/acquire.html) help?

Comment: @Skillmon: For some reason, I cannot load that page from where I am. I have deleted cache and cookies and changed browsers but it does not seem to help.

Comment: try https://www.tug.org/texlive

Comment: For some reason I cannot access either link via my ISP's wired connection.

I used the hotspot from my mobile phone, using a different ISP, and can now access the link to the torrent which is http://www.tug.org/texlive/files/texlive2018-20180414.iso.torrent

Thanks @Skillmon. How do I accept your answer?

Comment: You don't because those are comments, if you want to, I can write up an answer from them and you can accept that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Many links related to TeXLive can be found at https://www.tug.org/texlive/

The different ways to acquire TeXLive are listed at https://www.tug.org/texlive/acquire.html

That list also contains the link to the .iso file https://www.tug.org/texlive/acquire-iso.html where you can choose between CTAN mirrors or torrent.

The direct link to the torrent currently (25th June 2018) is https://www.tug.org/texlive/files/texlive2018-20180414.iso.torrent