# Where can I get the TeXLive 2019 torrent file?

Tags: texlive

I have searched the Web but am unable to get a link to the torrent file for TeXLive 2019.

This appears to be a frequent problem since I found a similar question about TexLive 2018: [Where can I get the TeXLive 2018 torrent file?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/437751/33634).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can browse https://www.tug.org/texlive/files. There you'll find `.torrent` files for TeXLive from 2009 all the way to the current one.

TeXLive 2019, specifically, is at https://www.tug.org/texlive/files/texlive2019-20190410.iso.torrent
and TeXLive 2020, at https://www.tug.org/texlive/files/texlive2020-20200406.iso.torrent.